# SVG transform and/or transform-origin not working properly on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, scale

Here is the problem: I want to scale SVGs rects' height and width on hover and keep it in place. It's that simple. It seems to work on Chrome, Edge and Safari. But n Firefox it just breaks. Same thing for `transform: translate(-25%,-25%);` which is commented out.
Questions:

- Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Where?
- Is there a workaround for this?

My site: http://voemap.com.br/destinos/

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 1200 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 768;version:1"><style type="text/css">  
            .st0 {
                fill: #008E8E;
            }

            .st1 {
                fill: #BEFF8C;
            }

            .st2 {
                fill: #9AD694;
            }

            .st3 {
                fill: #00A9AB;
            }

            .st4 {
                fill: #836A84;
            }

            .st5 {
                font-family: &#39;BebasNeue&#39;;
            }

            .st6 {
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            .st7 {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                fill: #C96ED5;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
                -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
                -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
                -webkit-transform-origin: 74% 47%;
                -moz-transform-origin: 74% 47%;
                -ms-transform-origin: 74% 47%;
                -o-transform-origin: 74% 47%;
                transform-origin: 74% 47%;
                /*transform: translate(-25%,-25%);*/
            }

            .st7:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                -moz-transform: scale(1.6);
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
                -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
                transform: scale(1.6);
            }

            /* .st8 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            } */

            .st9 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 2.9735, 2.9735;
            }

            .st10 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 3.0523, 3.0523;
            }

            .st11 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 3.0534, 3.0534;
            }

            .st12 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 2.9098, 2.9098;
            }

            .st13 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 3.0074, 3.0074;
            }

            .st14 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 2.9956, 2.9956;
            }

            .st15 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #E03DCB;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;
            }

            .dashed {
                stroke-dasharray: 2;
                stroke: #BEFF8C;
                stroke-width: 2.5px;
                stroke-dashoffset: 2;
                stroke-opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            }

            .passagem {
                stroke-dasharray: 1000;
                stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            }
        </style><g id="Layer_1"><path class="st0" d="M1048.5 298.4l-76.7 122.3 -56.3 150.9 -217.6-12.1c-2.4-4.6-10.4-20.2-18.7-35.6 -5.8-10.7-10.6-19.3-14.3-25.4 -5.2-8.6-7.5-11.5-9.1-12.4l-9.9-13 73-149.4 -88.3-80.3 1.6-32.3c11.7-3.1 76.8-13.8 128.5-22 3.8 4.8 23.7 29.8 43.5 54.6 12.9 16.1 23.3 29 31 38.3 14.8 18.1 15.4 18.3 16.4 18.6 0.3 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.9 0.2 1.4 0 2.8-1.2 4.9-3.3 1.7-1.6 4-4.1 6.8-7.2 4.8-5.3 11.3-12.7 19.2-22.1 11.1-13.1 22.2-26.4 25.8-30.8L1048.5 298.4z"/><path class="st0" d="M1046.1 588.7l-4.7 85.7 -78.4-1.8 -21.3 12.8 -35.6-17.8 -0.5 1 14.2-93.6 56.9-152.6c17 6.1 26.6 10.7 29 12.6 -2.1 8.2-7 46.1-8.6 58.3l-0.2 1.5 34 27c-0.9 3.2-2.8 10.6-4.7 18.1 -5.2 20.8-4.8 22.6-4.5 23.6 0.3 1.1 0.7 2.9 13.4 14.9C1039.7 582.9 1044.2 587 1046.1 588.7z"/><path class="st0" d="M878.2 111l43.2 86.3 -15.2 35.4c-17.9 21.7-46.5 55.6-53.6 62.1 -8.5-9.3-54.2-66.3-86.1-106.5 33-5.3 59.2-9.3 59.9-9.4l1.1-0.2L878.2 111z"/><path class="st0" d="M712.3 325.1l-72.7 148.8 11 14.4c-1.2 1.9-2.3 5.2-3.6 10.2 -1.6 6-3.2 14-4.5 22 -0.9 5.5-1.5 10.5-1.8 14.1 -0.1 1.6-0.2 2.9-0.2 4.1 -12.4 0.3-64.2 0.1-99.7-0.2L480 506.3l-1.4 1.3c-16.3 15.9-35 33.4-38.2 35.3 -1.6 0.3-7.4 2.1-37.2 12.8 -17.5 6.3-34.8 12.7-35 12.7l1.1 3L140 480.9c3.7-6.4 9.6-15.7 18.7-29.2 11.2-16.7 22.6-32.6 25.2-36.3l83.6-21.3 -8.8-153.4 74.5-54.2c4 3 15.1 11.2 26.3 20.1 24.4 19.2 28.3 24.5 29 25.7 -0.1 0.7 0.1 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.3 0.5 1.1 1.2 2.6 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.5 0 5 0 47.4-21.5 20.7-10.5 40.9-21.2 41.1-21.3l1-0.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 2.8-1 11.3-1.7 19.1-1.8l13 97.9 26.5 19.6 55.2-59.7 32-0.8L712.3 325.1z"/><path class="st0" d="M626.9 210.3l-1.6 31.8 -32.9 0.8 -53.5 57.9L518 285.3 504.7 185h-2.3c-5.3 0-16.7 0.2-22.5 1.9L442 120.7l56.4 14.5 0.9-0.5c2.9-1.6 63.7-35.4 83.6-47.1l-0.1 0.5 2.3-1.6c1.8 8 8 25 21 59.6 8.7 23.2 20.5 54.5 21.4 61.5 -0.5 0.5-0.8 1.2-0.8 2C626.8 209.8 626.8 210 626.9 210.3z"/><path class="st0" d="M589.4 624.9l-21.3 78c-8.3-2.7-37.4-14.1-63.4-24.3 -52.6-20.7-77-30.1-82.9-31.2 -0.8-1.6-2.8-9-2.7-42.6 0.1-19.7 0.9-38.8 0.9-39l0.2-4.7 -32.2 17.7 -15.7-6.2c26.6-9.8 65.2-23.7 69-24.5 1.4 0 3.3-0.8 22.4-18.7 7.3-6.9 14.5-13.8 17.4-16.7l56.5 29.9c-0.3 4.9-1.1 19.5-1.5 34.1 -0.3 10.5-0.4 18.9-0.2 25.1 0.3 11.3 1.4 13.6 3.5 14.5C543.2 618 577.2 623.1 589.4 624.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M381.9 582.1l-73.7 40.4 -61.4-14.9 14.8-68.6 -57.7 37.2c-4.4-5.6-17.9-22.6-31.9-39.6 -27.6-33.6-35.5-41.1-38.4-43 0.3-1.1 1.2-3.5 3.8-8.2L381.9 582.1z"/><path class="st0" d="M1053.2 294.8l-141.3-62 15.2-35.6 -48.1-96.1 -54.5 72.7c-15.6 2.4-165.6 25.8-192.1 31.9 -1.4-7.6-7.7-24.9-21.5-61.5 -8.8-23.3-20.7-54.9-21.2-61.1 0.4-0.6 0.7-1.3 0.5-2.3l1.4-5.1 -4.8 3.3c-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0.1 -0.6 0.2-1.1 0.6-1.4 1 -9.1 5.9-78.7 44.6-87.6 49.5l-66.4-17.1 43.8 76.7c-28.6 15.1-72.3 37.4-82.1 40.6 -1.1-2-3.6-4.7-8.5-9.2 -4.8-4.3-11.5-10-20.1-16.8 -14.6-11.5-29.5-22.5-29.7-22.6l-1.5-1.1 -79.9 58.1 8.7 151.9 -81.3 20.8 -0.6 0.8c-0.1 0.2-13.6 19-26.7 38.5 -27.1 40.4-25.8 43.9-25 45.9 0.4 1 1.2 1.8 2.2 2.1 1.2 0.6 7.4 5.4 37.9 42.7 16.7 20.3 32.5 40.4 32.7 40.6l1.5 1.9 51.1-32.9 -13.2 61.2 68.4 16.6 105.6-57.9c-0.2 7-0.7 20.9-0.7 35 -0.1 41.4 3 44.7 4.3 46.1 0.9 1 1.9 1.2 2.6 1.2 4.4 0.4 49.2 18 82 30.9 44.9 17.6 61.8 24.1 66.3 25.1l2.4-2.1 -4-1.1 5.1 1.4 0.5-1.7 23.1-84.5 -2.9-0.4c-17.6-2.6-45.9-6.9-51.3-8.4 -1.7-5.5-1-37.8 0.8-67.9 7.1 0.1 28.3 0.2 49.2 0.3 15 0.1 27 0.1 35.6 0 5.1 0 9.1-0.1 11.8-0.1 1.5 0 2.6-0.1 3.4-0.1 1.2-0.1 3.3-0.2 3.6-2.3 0.1-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.5-2 -0.2-2.3 0.6-11.6 3-24.6 2.3-12.4 4.4-19.6 5.6-22.7 5.9 7.6 24 40.8 39.4 71.1l0.7 1.3 219.7 12.2 -14.1 93.5 3.7 2 1.9-3.7 14.2-93.6 56.9-152.6c17 6.1 26.6 10.7 29 12.6 -2.1 8.2-7 46.1-8.6 58.3l-0.2 1.5 34 27c-0.9 3.2-2.8 10.6-4.7 18.1 -5.2 20.8-4.8 22.6-4.5 23.6 0.3 1.1 0.7 2.9 13.4 14.9 4.5 4.2 8.9 8.3 10.9 10l-4.7 85.8 -78.3-1.8 -21.3 12.8 -35.6-17.8 -0.5 1 -1.9 3.7 1.2 0.6 36.9 18.5 22.5-13.5 76.7 1.7 0.4 0 0 0.4 4.7 0 5.2-93.7c0 0-2.2 1.1-3.8 1.7l3.8-1.7c-9.6-8.7-23.3-21.7-24.6-24 0-3.3 4.8-23.1 9.6-40.8l0.5-1.7 -34.4-27.3c2.7-20.8 7.1-53.4 8.3-56.5 0.4-0.8 0.4-1.8 0.1-2.7 -0.6-1.4-1.9-4.8-31.8-15.6l74.4-117.5 1-1.6 1.2-2.6L1053.2 294.8zM826.4 178.8l1.1-0.2 50.7-67.6 43.2 86.3 -15.2 35.4c-17.9 21.7-46.5 55.6-53.6 62.1 -8.5-9.3-54.2-66.3-86.1-106.5C799.6 183 825.8 178.9 826.4 178.8zM442 120.7l56.4 14.5 0.9-0.5c2.9-1.6 63.7-35.4 83.6-47.1l-0.1 0.5 2.3-1.6c1.8 8 8 25 21 59.6 8.7 23.2 20.5 54.5 21.4 61.5 -0.5 0.5-0.8 1.2-0.8 2 0 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.1 0.7l-1.6 31.8 -32.9 0.8 -53.5 57.9L518 285.3 504.7 185h-2.3c-5.3 0-16.7 0.2-22.5 1.9L442 120.7zM308.2 622.5l-61.4-14.9 14.8-68.6 -57.7 37.2c-4.4-5.6-17.9-22.6-31.9-39.6 -27.6-33.6-35.5-41.1-38.4-43 0.3-1.1 1.2-3.5 3.8-8.2l244.6 96.6L308.2 622.5zM589.4 624.9l-21.3 78c-8.3-2.7-37.4-14.1-63.4-24.3 -52.6-20.7-77-30.1-82.9-31.2 -0.8-1.6-2.8-9-2.7-42.6 0.1-19.7 0.9-38.8 0.9-39l0.2-4.7 -32.2 17.7 -15.7-6.2c26.6-9.8 65.2-23.7 69-24.5 1.4 0 3.3-0.8 22.4-18.7 7.3-6.9 14.5-13.8 17.4-16.7l56.5 29.9c-0.3 4.9-1.1 19.5-1.5 34.1 -0.3 10.5-0.4 18.9-0.2 25.1 0.3 11.3 1.4 13.6 3.5 14.5C543.2 618 577.2 623.1 589.4 624.9zM647 498.5c-1.6 6-3.2 14-4.5 22 -0.9 5.5-1.5 10.5-1.8 14.1 -0.1 1.6-0.2 2.9-0.2 4.1 -12.4 0.3-64.2 0.1-99.7-0.2L480 506.3l-1.4 1.3c-16.3 15.9-35 33.4-38.2 35.3 -1.6 0.3-7.4 2.1-37.2 12.8 -17.5 6.3-34.8 12.7-35 12.7l1.1 3L140 480.9c3.7-6.4 9.6-15.7 18.7-29.2 11.2-16.7 22.6-32.6 25.2-36.3l83.6-21.3 -8.8-153.4 74.5-54.2c4 3 15.1 11.2 26.3 20.1 24.4 19.2 28.3 24.5 29 25.7 -0.1 0.7 0.1 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.3 0.5 1.1 1.2 2.6 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.5 0 5 0 47.4-21.5 20.7-10.5 40.9-21.2 41.1-21.3l1-0.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 2.8-1 11.3-1.7 19.1-1.8l13 97.9 26.5 19.6 55.2-59.7 32-0.8 85.5 77.8 -72.7 148.8 11 14.4C649.4 490.2 648.3 493.5 647 498.5zM972.5 418.6l-0.7 2.2 -56.3 150.9 -217.6-12.1c-2.4-4.6-10.4-20.2-18.7-35.6 -5.8-10.7-10.6-19.3-14.3-25.4 -5.2-8.6-7.5-11.5-9.1-12.4l-9.9-13 73-149.4 -88.3-80.3 1.6-32.3c11.7-3.1 76.8-13.8 128.5-22 3.8 4.8 23.7 29.8 43.5 54.6 12.9 16.1 23.3 29 31 38.3 14.8 18.1 15.4 18.3 16.4 18.6 0.3 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.9 0.2 1.4 0 2.8-1.2 4.9-3.3 1.7-1.6 4-4.1 6.8-7.2 4.8-5.3 11.3-12.7 19.2-22.1 11.1-13.1 22.2-26.4 25.8-30.8l139.2 61.1L972.5 418.6z"/><path class="st1" d="M1064.7 282.3l-76.7 122.3 -56.3 150.9 -217.6-12.1c-2.4-4.6-10.4-20.2-18.7-35.6 -5.8-10.7-10.6-19.3-14.3-25.4 -5.2-8.6-7.5-11.5-9.1-12.4l-9.9-13 73-149.4 -88.3-80.3 1.6-32.3c11.7-3.1 76.8-13.8 128.5-22 3.8 4.8 23.7 29.8 43.5 54.6 12.9 16.1 23.3 29 31 38.3 14.8 18.1 15.4 18.3 16.4 18.6 0.3 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.9 0.2 1.4 0 2.8-1.2 4.9-3.3 1.7-1.6 4-4.1 6.8-7.2 4.8-5.3 11.3-12.7 19.2-22.1 11.1-13.1 22.2-26.4 25.8-30.8L1064.7 282.3z"/><path class="st2" d="M1062.3 572.5l-4.7 85.7 -78.4-1.8 -21.3 12.8 -35.6-17.8 -0.5 1 14.2-93.6 56.9-152.6c17 6.1 26.6 10.7 29 12.6 -2.1 8.2-7 46.1-8.6 58.3l-0.2 1.5 34 27c-0.9 3.2-2.8 10.6-4.7 18.1 -5.2 20.8-4.8 22.6-4.5 23.6 0.3 1.1 0.7 2.9 13.4 14.9C1055.8 566.7 1060.4 570.8 1062.3 572.5z"/><path class="st2" d="M894.4 94.9l43.2 86.3 -15.2 35.4c-17.9 21.7-46.5 55.6-53.6 62.1 -8.5-9.3-54.2-66.3-86.1-106.5 33-5.3 59.2-9.3 59.9-9.4l1.1-0.2L894.4 94.9z"/><path class="st1" d="M728.5 308.9l-72.7 148.8 11 14.4c-1.2 1.9-2.3 5.2-3.6 10.2 -1.6 6-3.2 14-4.5 22 -0.9 5.5-1.5 10.5-1.8 14.1 -0.1 1.6-0.2 2.9-0.2 4.1 -12.4 0.3-64.2 0.1-99.7-0.2l-60.8-32.2 -1.4 1.3c-16.3 15.9-35 33.4-38.2 35.3 -1.6 0.3-7.4 2.1-37.2 12.8 -17.5 6.3-34.8 12.7-35 12.7l1.1 3 -229.3-90.6c3.7-6.4 9.6-15.7 18.7-29.2 11.2-16.7 22.6-32.6 25.2-36.3l83.6-21.3 -8.8-153.4 74.5-54.2c4 3 15.1 11.2 26.3 20.1 24.4 19.2 28.3 24.5 29 25.7 -0.1 0.7 0.1 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.3 0.5 1.1 1.2 2.6 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.5 0 5 0 47.4-21.5 20.7-10.5 40.9-21.2 41.1-21.3l1-0.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 2.8-1 11.3-1.7 19.1-1.8l13 97.9 26.5 19.6 55.2-59.7 32-0.8L728.5 308.9z"/><path class="st2" d="M643.1 194.1l-1.6 31.8 -32.9 0.8 -53.5 57.9 -20.9-15.5 -13.3-100.3h-2.3c-5.3 0-16.7 0.2-22.5 1.9l-37.9-66.3 56.4 14.5 0.9-0.5c2.9-1.6 63.7-35.4 83.6-47.1l-0.1 0.5 2.3-1.6c1.8 8 8 25 21 59.6 8.7 23.2 20.5 54.5 21.4 61.5 -0.5 0.5-0.8 1.2-0.8 2C642.9 193.6 643 193.9 643.1 194.1z"/><path class="st2" d="M605.6 608.7l-21.3 78c-8.3-2.7-37.4-14.1-63.4-24.3 -52.6-20.7-77-30.1-82.9-31.2 -0.8-1.6-2.8-9-2.7-42.6 0.1-19.7 0.9-38.8 0.9-39l0.2-4.7 -32.2 17.7 -15.7-6.2c26.6-9.8 65.2-23.7 69-24.5 1.4 0 3.3-0.8 22.4-18.7 7.3-6.9 14.5-13.8 17.4-16.7l56.5 29.9c-0.3 4.9-1.1 19.5-1.5 34.1 -0.3 10.5-0.4 18.9-0.2 25.1 0.3 11.3 1.4 13.6 3.5 14.5C559.3 601.8 593.4 606.9 605.6 608.7z"/><path class="st2" d="M398.1 565.9l-73.7 40.4 -61.4-14.9 14.8-68.6L220 560c-4.4-5.6-17.9-22.6-31.9-39.6 -27.6-33.6-35.5-41.1-38.4-43 0.3-1.1 1.2-3.5 3.8-8.2L398.1 565.9z"/><path class="st3" d="M1069.4 278.6l-141.3-62 15.2-35.6 -48.1-96.1 -54.5 72.7c-15.6 2.4-165.6 25.8-192.1 31.9 -1.4-7.6-7.7-24.9-21.5-61.5 -8.8-23.3-20.7-54.9-21.2-61.1 0.4-0.6 0.7-1.3 0.5-2.3l1.4-5.1 -4.8 3.3c-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0.1 -0.6 0.2-1.1 0.6-1.4 1 -9.1 5.9-78.7 44.6-87.6 49.5l-66.4-17.1 43.8 76.7c-28.6 15.1-72.3 37.4-82.1 40.6 -1.1-2-3.6-4.7-8.5-9.2 -4.8-4.3-11.5-10-20.1-16.8 -14.6-11.5-29.5-22.5-29.7-22.6l-1.5-1.1 -79.9 58.1 8.7 151.9 -81.3 20.8 -0.6 0.8c-0.1 0.2-13.6 19-26.7 38.5 -27.1 40.4-25.8 43.9-25 45.9 0.4 1 1.2 1.8 2.2 2.1 1.2 0.6 7.4 5.4 37.9 42.7 16.7 20.3 32.5 40.4 32.7 40.6l1.5 1.9 51.1-32.9 -13.2 61.2 68.4 16.6L430.7 554c-0.2 7-0.7 20.9-0.7 35 -0.1 41.4 3 44.7 4.3 46.1 0.9 1 1.9 1.2 2.6 1.2 4.4 0.4 49.2 18 82 30.9 44.9 17.6 61.8 24.1 66.3 25.1l2.4-2.1 -4-1.1 5.1 1.4 0.5-1.7 23.1-84.5 -2.9-0.4c-17.6-2.6-45.9-6.9-51.3-8.4 -1.7-5.5-1-37.8 0.8-67.9 7.1 0.1 28.3 0.2 49.2 0.3 15 0.1 27 0.1 35.6 0 5.1 0 9.1-0.1 11.8-0.1 1.5 0 2.6-0.1 3.4-0.1 1.2-0.1 3.3-0.2 3.6-2.3 0.1-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.5-2 -0.2-2.3 0.6-11.6 3-24.6 2.3-12.4 4.4-19.6 5.6-22.7 5.9 7.6 24 40.8 39.4 71.1l0.7 1.3 219.7 12.2 -14.1 93.5 3.7 2 1.9-3.7 14.2-93.6 56.9-152.6c17 6.1 26.6 10.7 29 12.6 -2.1 8.2-7 46.1-8.6 58.3l-0.2 1.5 34 27c-0.9 3.2-2.8 10.6-4.7 18.1 -5.2 20.8-4.8 22.6-4.5 23.6 0.3 1.1 0.7 2.9 13.4 14.9 4.5 4.2 8.9 8.3 10.9 10l-4.7 85.8 -78.3-1.8 -21.3 12.8 -35.6-17.8 -0.5 1 -1.9 3.7 1.2 0.6 36.9 18.5 22.5-13.5 76.7 1.7 0.4 0 0 0.4 4.7 0 5.2-93.7c0 0-2.2 1.1-3.8 1.7l3.8-1.7c-9.6-8.7-23.3-21.7-24.6-24 0-3.3 4.8-23.1 9.6-40.8l0.5-1.7 -34.4-27.3c2.7-20.8 7.1-53.4 8.3-56.5 0.4-0.8 0.4-1.8 0.1-2.7 -0.6-1.4-1.9-4.8-31.8-15.6l74.4-117.5 1-1.6 1.2-2.6L1069.4 278.6zM842.6 162.6l1.1-0.2 50.7-67.6 43.2 86.3 -15.2 35.4c-17.9 21.7-46.5 55.6-53.6 62.1 -8.5-9.3-54.2-66.3-86.1-106.5C815.8 166.8 841.9 162.8 842.6 162.6zM458.1 104.5l56.4 14.5 0.9-0.5c2.9-1.6 63.7-35.4 83.6-47.1l-0.1 0.5 2.3-1.6c1.8 8 8 25 21 59.6 8.7 23.2 20.5 54.5 21.4 61.5 -0.5 0.5-0.8 1.2-0.8 2 0 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.1 0.7l-1.6 31.8 -32.9 0.8 -53.5 57.9 -20.9-15.5 -13.3-100.3h-2.3c-5.3 0-16.7 0.2-22.5 1.9L458.1 104.5zM324.3 606.3l-61.4-14.9 14.8-68.6L220 560c-4.4-5.6-17.9-22.6-31.9-39.6 -27.6-33.6-35.5-41.1-38.4-43 0.3-1.1 1.2-3.5 3.8-8.2l244.6 96.6L324.3 606.3zM605.6 608.7l-21.3 78c-8.3-2.7-37.4-14.1-63.4-24.3 -52.6-20.7-77-30.1-82.9-31.2 -0.8-1.6-2.8-9-2.7-42.6 0.1-19.7 0.9-38.8 0.9-39l0.2-4.7 -32.2 17.7 -15.7-6.2c26.6-9.8 65.2-23.7 69-24.5 1.4 0 3.3-0.8 22.4-18.7 7.3-6.9 14.5-13.8 17.4-16.7l56.5 29.9c-0.3 4.9-1.1 19.5-1.5 34.1 -0.3 10.5-0.4 18.9-0.2 25.1 0.3 11.3 1.4 13.6 3.5 14.5C559.3 601.8 593.4 606.9 605.6 608.7zM663.2 482.3c-1.6 6-3.2 14-4.5 22 -0.9 5.5-1.5 10.5-1.8 14.1 -0.1 1.6-0.2 2.9-0.2 4.1 -12.4 0.3-64.2 0.1-99.7-0.2l-60.8-32.2 -1.4 1.3c-16.3 15.9-35 33.4-38.2 35.3 -1.6 0.3-7.4 2.1-37.2 12.8 -17.5 6.3-34.8 12.7-35 12.7l1.1 3 -229.3-90.6c3.7-6.4 9.6-15.7 18.7-29.2 11.2-16.7 22.6-32.6 25.2-36.3l83.6-21.3 -8.8-153.4 74.5-54.2c4 3 15.1 11.2 26.3 20.1 24.4 19.2 28.3 24.5 29 25.7 -0.1 0.7 0.1 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.3 0.5 1.1 1.2 2.6 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.5 0 5 0 47.4-21.5 20.7-10.5 40.9-21.2 41.1-21.3l1-0.5c0 0 0 0 0 0 2.8-1 11.3-1.7 19.1-1.8l13 97.9 26.5 19.6 55.2-59.7 32-0.8 85.5 77.8 -72.7 148.8 11 14.4C665.6 474 664.5 477.3 663.2 482.3zM988.6 402.4l-0.7 2.2 -56.3 150.9 -217.6-12.1c-2.4-4.6-10.4-20.2-18.7-35.6 -5.8-10.7-10.6-19.3-14.3-25.4 -5.2-8.6-7.5-11.5-9.1-12.4l-9.9-13 73-149.4 -88.3-80.3 1.6-32.3c11.7-3.1 76.8-13.8 128.5-22 3.8 4.8 23.7 29.8 43.5 54.6 12.9 16.1 23.3 29 31 38.3 14.8 18.1 15.4 18.3 16.4 18.6 0.3 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.9 0.2 1.4 0 2.8-1.2 4.9-3.3 1.7-1.6 4-4.1 6.8-7.2 4.8-5.3 11.3-12.7 19.2-22.1 11.1-13.1 22.2-26.4 25.8-30.8l139.2 61.1L988.6 402.4z"/></g><g id="Layer_3"><path class="st8" d="M402.5 265.5c0 0 0.5-0.2 1.3-0.7"/><path class="st9 passagem" d="M406.5 263.6c15.3-7 71.3-29.6 123-13.1 58.7 18.7 72.8 68.5 75.5 81.1" data-origins='["manaus","cachoeira"]' id="1"/><path class="st9 dashed" d="M406.5 263.6c15.3-7 71.3-29.6 123-13.1 58.7 18.7 72.8 68.5 75.5 81.1" id="1"/><path class="st8" d="M605.3 333c0.2 1 0.2 1.5 0.2 1.5"/><path class="st8" d="M605.5 334.5c-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.6-1.4"/><path class="st10 passagem" d="M603.6 330.3c-19.4-41.2-53.9-56-87.4-40.2" data-origins='["manaus","barcelos"]' id="2"/><path class="st10 dashed" d="M603.6 330.3c-19.4-41.2-53.9-56-87.4-40.2" id="2"/><path class="st8" d="M514.8 290.8c-0.4 0.2-0.9 0.4-1.3 0.7"/><path class="st8" d="M816 324c0-0.5 0-1-0.1-1.5"/><path class="st11 passagem" d="M815.6 319.5c-3.2-25.5-25.6-41.8-52.3-34.8" data-origins='["santarem","trombetas"]' id="3"/><path class="st11 dashed" d="M815.6 319.5c-3.2-25.5-25.6-41.8-52.3-34.8" id="3"/><path class="st8" d="M761.9 285.1c-0.5 0.1-1 0.3-1.4 0.4"/><path class="st8" d="M884 357c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.5"/><path class="st12 passagem" d="M883.3 352.6c-5.5-26.4-35.8-41-63.6-30.7" data-origins='["santarem","altamira"]' id="4"/><path class="st12 dashed" d="M883.3 352.6c-5.5-26.4-35.8-41-63.6-30.7" id="4"/><path class="st8" d="M818.4 322.4c-0.5 0.2-0.9 0.4-1.4 0.6"/><path class="st8" d="M744.5 389.5c-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.6-1.4"/><path class="st13 passagem" d="M742.6 385.4c-20.7-42.6-74.7-71.8-131.8-52.4" data-origins='["manaus","itaituba"]' id="5"/><path class="st13 dashed" d="M742.6 385.4c-20.7-42.6-74.7-71.8-131.8-52.4" id="5"/><path class="st8" d="M609.4 333.5c-0.5 0.2-0.9 0.3-1.4 0.5"/><path class="st8" d="M461 336c0 0 0.3-0.4 0.9-1.2"/><path class="st14 passagem" d="M463.8 332.5c7.2-8.1 28.8-27.5 69.2-27.5 41.5 0 64.1 20.3 70.5 27.2" data-origins='["manaus","tefe"]' id="6"/><path class="st14 dashed" d="M463.8 332.5c7.2-8.1 28.8-27.5 69.2-27.5 41.5 0 64.1 20.3 70.5 27.2" id="6"/><path class="st8" d="M604.5 333.4c0.6 0.7 1 1.1 1 1.1"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M286 463c0 0 2.5-78.2 62-115 55-34 112-13 112-13" data-origins='["tefe","eirunepe"]' id="7"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M286 463c0 0 2.5-78.2 62-115 55-34 112-13 112-13" id="7"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M467 491c0 0-0.7-62.9 47-114 42-45 92-42 92-42" data-origins='["manaus","labrea"]' id="8"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M467 491c0 0-0.7-62.9 47-114 42-45 92-42 92-42" id="8"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M381 395c-3-13 35-63 80-59" data-origins='["tefe","carauari"]' id="9"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M381 395c-3-13 35-63 80-59" id="9"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M744 389c30-40 89-48 141-31" data-origins='["itaituba","altamira"]' id="10"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M744 389c30-40 89-48 141-31" id="10"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M714 310c-9-18-78-30-108 24" data-origins='["manaus","parintins"]' id="11"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M714 310c-9-18-78-30-108 24" id="11"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M758 285c-18-23-129-41-152 48" data-origins='["manaus","trombetas"]' id="12"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M758 285c-18-23-129-41-152 48" id="12"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M476 372c-16-17-73-21-95 23" data-origins='["coari","carauari"]' id="13"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M476 372c-16-17-73-21-95 23" id="13"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M606 335c-49-28-107-13-130 37" data-origins='["manaus","coari"]' id="14"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M606 335c-49-28-107-13-130 37" id="14"/><path class="st15 passagem" d="M966 272c-50-22-121-8-149 51" data-origins='["belem","santarem"]' id="15"/><path class="st15 dashed" d="M966 272c-50-22-121-8-149 51" id="15"/></g><g id="Layer_2"><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 583.0146 354.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Manaus</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 649.6504 316.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Parintins</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 451.2983 298.0388)" class="st4 st5 st6">  barcelos</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 438.0757 326.0388)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Tefé</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.9709 393.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Coari</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 324.9893 264.1382)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st4 st5 st6">  São Gabriel</tspan><tspan x="-11.9" y="15.8" class="st4 st5 st6">   da Cachoeira</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 354.0093 415.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Carauari</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 754.9995 260.6572)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st4 st5 st6">  Porto</tspan><tspan x="0" y="15.8" class="st4 st5 st6">  Trombetas</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 786.4619 343.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Santarém</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 719.6108 409.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Itaituba</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 856.5591 376.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Altamira</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 948.8022 291.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Belém</text><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 258.9185 482.6572)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Eirunepé</text><rect x="602" y="330" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="manaus"/><rect x="710" y="306.6" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="parintins"/><rect x="812" y="320" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="santarem"/><rect x="740" y="385" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="itaituba"/><rect x="963" y="267" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="belem"/><rect x="880" y="353" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="altamira"/><rect x="756" y="281" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="trombetas"/><rect x="510" y="288" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="barcelos"/><rect x="456" y="331" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="tefe"/><rect x="472" y="369" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="coari"/><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 417.0393 497.0391)" class="st4 st5 st6">  Lábrea</text><rect x="463" y="487" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="labrea"/><rect x="377" y="391" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="carauari"/><rect x="281" y="459" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="eirunepe"/><rect x="398" y="262" class="st7" width="10" height="10" rx="50" ry="50" name="cachoeira"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: This is a Chrome bug that it seems other browsers may have copied. That's a shame as Chrome plan to fix their bug and change to Firefox's implementation. You're assuming the box for transforms is the fill box, it's not it's the viewBox.

Comment: Also if the w3c write a specification and Firefox implements it as written but Chrome doesn't and then the other browsers either copy Chrome or don't implement it at all, how is Firefox "not working properly"?

Comment: Yes, after a long research I stumbled upon these informations. I will keep this topic open until someone or myself find a workaround for this. There are many around here, but none of them worked out for me.